# String Date Value Converting

Tags: java

I am converting `String` to `Date` format. But it returns `"Unparseable date"`. for example,

`String date= "Wednesday, May 15, 2013";`

I want to convert this to String like `"2013-05-15"`   How to do that?

Comment: Check the JavaDoc for [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) twice: Once to parse a `Date`, the other to render it in the desired format:

```
Date date;
String display = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(
        new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy").parse(date)
    );
```

Your example date is unfortunate, because it uses the only 3-letter month "May", so I can't tell if your month names are all truncated to 3 letters, or if they are the full name. I have assumed months to be the full name, but if they are truncated, change `MMMM` to `MMM` in the second format string.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might help (parse the date string to date object and format it back in the new format):

```
    String dateString  = "Wednesday, May 15, 2013";
    DateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy"); 
    Date date = format1.parse(dateString);

    DateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
    String updatedDateString = format2.format(date);
    System.out.println("Updated Date > "+updatedDateString);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experiments with this, you need to do something like the below...Refer to the API for understanding how to construct your format strings. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/text/DateFormat.html

```
String myDateAsString = "Wednesday, May 15, 2013";
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMM d, yyyy");
Date d = new Date();
try {
    d = df.parse(myDateAsString);
} catch (ParseException e1) {
    System.out.println("Could not parse...something wrong....");
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
df.applyPattern("yyyy-MM-d");
String convertedDate = df.format(d);
System.out.println(convertedDate);
```

This will be a good approach.

Comment: Want to point out this should have a miniscule / slight amount better performance the other approaches offered because you only create one Date and one DateFormat object. The SimpleDateFormat.applyPattern method is meant for exactly situations like this where you take one date format, then convert it in another format.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class StringDate {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException{
        String dateString  = "Wednesday, May 15, 2013";
        DateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("E, MMM dd, yyyy"); 
        Date date = format1.parse(dateString);
        DateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
        String updatedDateString = format2.format(date);
        System.out.println("Updated Date > "+updatedDateString);
    }
}
```